# What causes these chips in a cement brick wall, and how can I fix them?

Tags: repair, walls, basement, brick, cement

I have found my exposed basement cement wall which is about 15 x 10 in size to have quite a few areas where there is a cracked chip ranging from approx 0.5" in diameter to 2" in diameter and a few millimeters deep.
[image: This is what it looks like]

On removing the chip I find that all of them have a brown powdered center
[image: An example of a 1" diameter chip exposed]
I also have something similar on the outside of my house. I looked online and could find no information on these. I'm not sure if this is something as a result of a pest problem or something structural

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try looking up "tie rods"? http://www.trxplug.com/rod-hole-information/